# I don't see an Angular component in the developer tools for debugging in Chrome

Tags: angular, chrome-debugging

I have this component working fine

[image]

But here I don't see it

[image]

Is in my app.module too

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can click the vertical three dots that can see in the screen shot and there may be an option call openfile. From that you can search with your file name.

after clicking three dots:

[image]

after click open file:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try to use **sourceMap: true** into your angular.json, it allow you to apply ts code to the chrome debugger. Then you **ctrl + p** to find your file name.

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        ...
        "sourceMap": true,
        ...
      },
    ...
}
```